# Creation of Position vectors in Convolution Neural Network for Relation Classification

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This question pertains to the use of position vectors in CNN for relation classification as described in multiple publications such as the following by Zeng et al: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C14-1220

I am trying to implement such a model in tensorflow. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any benefit to using randomly initialized vectors for denoting positional information? For instance, why not use one-hot vector encoding with say 100 dimensions to denote the positions? Is it not recommended to combine one-hot vectors with dense word vectors?
2. Is there a minimum dimension the positional vectors should have, depending on the dimensions of the word vectors? For instance, suppose the word vector dimension is 500, will a dimension of say 10 for the position vectors be too small to be of value in the model? Is there a range of dimensions that is known to perform well with position vectors?
3. Does the distance between the randomly initialized vectors for encoding positional information matter?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to look into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1, I don't have an explanation why combining one-hot and dense representations is bad, but empirically, looking at results reported by other people, it seems to be better to learn embeddings for the positions as well.

Yoav Goldberg also notes this in his [NLP Deep Learning book](http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00762ED1V01Y201703HLT037) (p. 96):

> In the “traditional” NLP setup,
>   distances are usually encoded by binning the distances into several groups (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5–10,
>   10+) and associating each bin with a one-hot vector. In a neural architecture, where the input
>   vector is not composed of binary indicator features, it may seem natural to allocate a single input
>   entry to the distance feature, where the numeric value of that entry is the distance.
>
> However, this
>   approach is not taken in practice. Instead, distance features are encoded similarly to the other
>   feature types: each bin is associated with a d-dimensional vector, and these distance-embedding
>   vectors are then trained as regular parameters in the network [dos Santos et al., 2015, Nguyen
>   and Grishman, 2015, Zeng et al., 2014, Zhu et al., 2015a].

Maybe you can find more insights into why embeddings are better by looking into the cited papers.

With regard to question 2, I would say as long as the dimensionality is big enough for the model to learn different embeddings for each position you want to encode, it should be fine. So they could be quite small in practice.